# STM Assembly instruction set to reserve data location respectivly, like PIC Assembly "ORG","RES"

Tags: assembly, stm8

I am working on STM8S microcontroller, and I need to reserve absolute data locations for my variables via using assembly.

So, I try to "LD" instructions but I couldn't.

In PIC assembly I have a part of code like this:

```
       ORG  0X40    ; origin set
cnt         RES  1  ; 1 byte reserve at 0x040 address
cnt1        RES  1  ; 1 byte reserve at 0x041 address 
test        RES  2  ; 2 byte reserve at 0x042 address
test1       RES  1  ; 1 byte reserve at 0x044 address
```

This is what I need and I want to do it in STM8S Assembly literally.

Comment: What do you mean "I couldn't" with `LD` instructions?  Isn't that a load?

Comment: I mean I try related instruction sets like `"LD A,#$55","LD A,$50" ` etc. where "stm8s programming manual".

Comment: Loading from an absolute address (or loading a pointer to that absolute address) doesn't imply anything about reserving space at that address.  You can do one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ds.b or ds.w followed by number of bytes/words to reserve.
Example: 
My_Bytes ds.b 100
This will reserve 100 bytes, and you can access same using the label "My_Bytes".